# Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes into dex format. (I researched and still don't know)

Tags: android, build, google-play-games, unity-game-engine

Im using unity 5.4.3.1f and just imported google play games package on a mac (GooglePlayGamesPlugin-0.9.34.unitypackage).

I have researched this error and found that it is caused by duplicate .jar files yet I have searched and searched and none appear. I was not getting this error before updating my JDK and adding the google games plugin. Could this error also be caused by duplicate .jar files in android-sdk because I have not yet checked that and have added some libraries.

I know this is a common error but if anyone sees anything different that would be really helpful.

Here is Log:

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to convert classes 

into dex format. See the Console for details.
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_92.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/connorkordes/Downloads/android-sdk-macosx/tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer/Tools/sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/BuildConfig;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoJellyBeanMr2;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoStubImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/animation/AnimatorCompatHelper;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle;
Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle$1;

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:608)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:311)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at SDKMain.main(SDKMain.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:600)
    ... 9 more
]
stdout[
processing archive /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/connorkordes/FaceIt/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/MainLibProj/libs/./play-games-plugin-support.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/google/
ignored resource com/google/games/
ignored resource com/google/games/bridge/
processing com/google/games/bridge/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/NativeBridgeActivity.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment$1.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenFragment$TokenRequest.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenPendingResult.class...
processing com/google/games/bridge/TokenResult.class...
processing archive /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/connorkordes/FaceIt/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/cardview-v7-23.2.1/bin/classes.jar...
processing android/support/v7/cardview/BuildConfig.class...
processing android/support/v7/widget/CardView.class...
processing android/support/v7/widget/CardViewApi21.class...
processing android/support/v7/widget/CardViewDelegate.class...
processing android/support/v7/widget/CardViewEclairMr1.class...
processing android/support/v7/widget/CardViewEclairMr1$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/widget/CardViewImpl.class...
processing android/support/v7/widget/CardViewJellybeanMr1.class...
processing android/support/v7/widget/CardViewJellybeanMr1$1.class...
processing android/support/v7/widget/RoundRectDrawable.class...
processing android/support/v7/widget/RoundRectDrawableWithShadow.class...
processing android/support/v7/widget/RoundRectDrawableWithShadow$RoundRectHelper.class...
processing archive /Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/connorkordes/FaceIt/Temp/StagingArea/android-libraries/facebook-android-sdk-4.11.0/bin/classes.jar...
ignored resource META-INF/
ignored resource META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
ignored resource android/
ignored resource android/support/
ignored resource android/support/v7/
ignored resource android/support/v7/cardview/
ignored resource com/
ignored resource com/facebook/
processing com/facebook/AccessToken.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessToken$1.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessToken$2.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessToken$AccessTokenCreationCallback.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessToken$AccessTokenRefreshCallback.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessTokenCache.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessTokenCache$SharedPreferencesTokenCachingStrategyFactory.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessTokenManager.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessTokenManager$1.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessTokenManager$2.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessTokenManager$3.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessTokenManager$4.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessTokenManager$RefreshResult.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessTokenSource.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessTokenTracker.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessTokenTracker$1.class...
processing com/facebook/AccessTokenTracker$CurrentAccessTokenBroadcastReceiver.class...
processing com/facebook/BuildConfig.class...
processing com/facebook/CallbackManager.class...
processing com/facebook/CallbackManager$Factory.class...
processing com/facebook/CustomTabActivity.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookActivity.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookBroadcastReceiver.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookButtonBase.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookButtonBase$1.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookCallback.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookContentProvider.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookDialog.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookDialogException.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookException.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookGraphResponseException.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookOperationCanceledException.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookRequestError.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookRequestError$1.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookRequestError$Category.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookRequestError$Range.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookSdk.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookSdk$1.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookSdk$2.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookSdk$3.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookSdk$4.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookSdk$InitializeCallback.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookSdkNotInitializedException.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookSdkVersion.class...
processing com/facebook/FacebookServiceException.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$1.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$2.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$3.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$4.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$5.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$6.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$7.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$Attachment.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$Callback.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$GraphJSONArrayCallback.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$GraphJSONObjectCallback.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$KeyValueSerializer.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$OnProgressCallback.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$ParcelableResourceWithMimeType.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$ParcelableResourceWithMimeType$1.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequest$Serializer.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequestAsyncTask.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequestBatch.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequestBatch$Callback.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphRequestBatch$OnProgressCallback.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphResponse.class...
processing com/facebook/GraphResponse$PagingDirection.class...
processing com/facebook/HttpMethod.class...
processing com/facebook/LegacyTokenHelper.class...
processing com/facebook/LoggingBehavior.class...
processing com/facebook/Profile.class...
processing com/facebook/Profile$1.class...
processing com/facebook/Profile$2.class...
processing com/facebook/ProfileCache.class...
processing com/facebook/ProfileManager.class...
processing com/facebook/ProfileTracker.class...
processing com/facebook/ProfileTracker$1.class...
processing com/facebook/ProfileTracker$ProfileBroadcastReceiver.class...
processing com/facebook/ProgressNoopOutputStream.class...
processing com/facebook/ProgressOutputStream.class...
processing com/facebook/ProgressOutputStream$1.class...
processing com/facebook/RequestOutputStream.class...
processing com/facebook/RequestProgress.class...
processing com/facebook/RequestProgress$1.class...
processing com/facebook/TestUserManager.class...
processing com/facebook/TestUserManager$Mode.class...
ignored resource com/facebook/appevents/
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsConstants.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$1.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$2.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$3.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$4.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$5.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$6.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$7.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$AccessTokenAppIdPair.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$AccessTokenAppIdPair$SerializationProxyV1.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$AppEvent.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$AppEvent$SerializationProxyV1.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$FlushBehavior.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$FlushReason.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$FlushResult.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$FlushStatistics.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$PersistedAppSessionInfo.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$PersistedAppSessionInfo$1.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$PersistedEvents.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsLogger$SessionEventsState.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/FacebookTimeSpentData.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/FacebookTimeSpentData$1.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/FacebookTimeSpentData$SerializationProxyV1.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/FacebookTimeSpentData$SerializationProxyV2.class...
ignored resource com/facebook/appevents/internal/
processing com/facebook/appevents/internal/ActivityLifecycleTracker.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/internal/ActivityLifecycleTracker$1.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/internal/ActivityLifecycleTracker$2.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/internal/ActivityLifecycleTracker$3.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/internal/ActivityLifecycleTracker$4.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/internal/ActivityLifecycleTracker$4$1.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/internal/Constants.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/internal/SessionInfo.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/internal/SessionLogger.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/internal/SourceApplicationInfo.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/internal/SourceApplicationInfo$1.class...
processing com/facebook/appevents/internal/SourceApplicationInfo$Factory.class...
ignored resource com/facebook/applinks/
processing com/facebook/applinks/AppLinkData.class...
processing com/facebook/applinks/AppLinkData$1.class...
processing com/facebook/applinks/AppLinkData$CompletionHandler.class...
processing com/facebook/applinks/FacebookAppLinkResolver.class...
processing com/facebook/applinks/FacebookAppLinkResolver$1.class...
processing com/facebook/applinks/FacebookAppLinkResolver$2.class...
ignored resource com/facebook/internal/
processing com/facebook/internal/AnalyticsEvents.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/AppCall.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/AppEventsLoggerUtility.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/AppEventsLoggerUtility$1.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/AppEventsLoggerUtility$GraphAPIActivityType.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/AttributionIdentifiers.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/AttributionIdentifiers$1.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/AttributionIdentifiers$GoogleAdInfo.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/AttributionIdentifiers$GoogleAdServiceConnection.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/BoltsMeasurementEventListener.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/BundleJSONConverter.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/BundleJSONConverter$1.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/BundleJSONConverter$2.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/BundleJSONConverter$3.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/BundleJSONConverter$4.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/BundleJSONConverter$5.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/BundleJSONConverter$6.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/BundleJSONConverter$7.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/BundleJSONConverter$Setter.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/CallbackManagerImpl.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/CallbackManagerImpl$Callback.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/CallbackManagerImpl$RequestCodeOffset.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/CollectionMapper.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/CollectionMapper$1.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/CollectionMapper$2.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/CollectionMapper$Collection.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/CollectionMapper$OnErrorListener.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/CollectionMapper$OnMapValueCompleteListener.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/CollectionMapper$OnMapperCompleteListener.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/CollectionMapper$ValueMapper.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/CustomTab.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/DialogFeature.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/DialogPresenter.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/DialogPresenter$ParameterProvider.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FacebookDialogBase.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FacebookDialogBase$ModeHandler.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FacebookDialogFragment.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FacebookDialogFragment$1.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FacebookDialogFragment$2.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FacebookRequestErrorClassification.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FacebookRequestErrorClassification$1.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FacebookRequestErrorClassification$2.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FacebookRequestErrorClassification$3.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FacebookWebFallbackDialog.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FacebookWebFallbackDialog$1.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FileLruCache.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FileLruCache$1.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FileLruCache$2.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FileLruCache$3.class...
processing com/facebook/internal/FileLruCache$BufferFile.<message truncated>
```

Comment: it's a pain.  this is the reason most folks just use Prime31 (and that is not THAT easy either)..